# Recreating or cloning Adminthml_System_Config blocks and functionality in a custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, module, configuration

I am writing a custom admin module, which is supposed to display chosen tabs / content blocks from System > Admin > Config (as they are there).

I was initially hoping to be able to do this via layout.xml or block/model class-group calls from within my module, but after reviewing Mage/Adminhtml, I am not so sure, this is the right call.

Naturally, repeating the blocks/functionality of `Mage::(Adminhtml/Config)` is an option, but I am wondering if there is any less-cumbersome way do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to display a "settings dashboard" on a custom route in the admin?

Comment: Yes, I want to display an excerpt from the output of "*/system_config/*", in my own module.

Sort of "Here are the essentials from System/Config that, you, dear admin-client, need to setup right away" type of module.